# Can comment votes sometimes be misleading?

Tags: discussion, comment-votes

I received a downvote yesterday to my answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354782/why-is-array0-1-2-the-same-as-array2-in-javascript/27354799#27354799, which brought me this question to mind.

I have a comment from the OP stating:

> **4**      it is for variable seperation not for array

Anyone who is a regular of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) knows how misleading the 
comment is. What I think would be more misleading is the 4 upvotes on the comment, which's adding more weight to the comment.

Can something be done to remove the extremely misleading comment, with votes from 4 rebellious users, or should it be left as such?

**P.S:** 
The answer which has been accepted (with a *negative* score, apparently for it's lack of quality) has the comment `"why Downvoted??"`, which has remarkably coincidental 4 votes.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing you can do other than to leave a "counter" comment. There's an incorrect comment with 473 upvotes on one of my answers. And I've learned to live with it.

Comment: Easy answer--JqueryKing has four socks.  Or four close friends who troll as ordered.  Flagged.

Comment: And this is why comment voting sucks. (brb, getting all my socks to vote on this comment)

Comment: @Mysticial in one of my answers, I took an effort to add a note referring screen shot of the comments with "hand made" selection highlighting [points that were buried under upvotes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mejbq.png)

Comment: *rebellious users*? What precisely do you think they are *rebelling* against? Users who want to censor comments or control what others are allowed to say? I find it pretty strange that a 36K+ user is complaining about receiving a single downvote at all, much less protesting comment votes with which you disagree.

Comment: @KenWhite rebelling against my answer, rebelling against the facts, please check the comment thread on the question of OP. And yes, please do check the comment on albert's answer. Many users are helping them to improve their answer, but they are payin no heed to it, and this, I find rebelling as they are downvoting what's correct and upvoting what's wrong or what can be said of as pure lack of quality. And I really don't see how I'm *complaining* about the downvote, when I've just mentioned it once, and that too because, the downvote made me realize what was going on.

Comment: The comment might have received 4 votes, but your response has received at least a dozen. The accepted answer has multiple downvotes (mine being one of them), and you can add yours as well. In addition, the question itself was a duplicate, has been closed as such, and has received multiple downvotes (including one from me) and a delete vote. What more can be done? (And posting here about a comment on a post that resulted in a single downvote for a high rep user is complaining simply by the fact you posted here. If everyone created a meta post for each downvote they received...)

Comment: @Ken White: He posted here first. He then posted the comment, presumably after Mysticial's comment. *Then* it got upvoted by the meta effect. He hasn't asked for anything more.

Answer (score 18):

> Can comment votes sometimes be misleading?

Yes.

> Can something be done to remove the extremely misleading comment, with votes from 4 rebellious users, or should it be left as such?

No.

Moderators normally are not supposed to judge the technical accuracies of comments/posts when deciding to delete or not.

If it is an answer but completely wrong you're just supposed to downvote and maybe leave a comment explaining why the answer is wrong.

Since there is no downvote option with comments, your only option is to ping the comment author in another comment explaining why their comment is wrong. And who knows, maybe they will decide to delete their comment. Or your comment may even get more upvotes than theirs.

But of course it doesn't matter what I have to say, lets see what [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3620/244519) has to say ~

> If a comment is wrong, respond to it with another comment. That provides a lot more information than a downvote which could mean anything.

Answer (score 11):

Comment votes are extremely misleading. It is unfortunate the only signal available is an upvote. Surely this gains traction over time as more and more uninformed viewers agree with the "popular" comment without even seeing that it may be controversial. Controversial comments only receive upvotes so the only way to provide the other side of that is to leave a comment (@Shog9, don't you see how this causes conflict in comments?).

I left a comment on your answer hopefully providing the explanation of the controversy. I also closed that question as a duplicate because it is about the comma operator and there was already a good candidate which discusses the comma operator in depth, as well as an upvote because your answer was correct - content first :D.

As for the existing comment, I flagged it as "obsolete" because it is no longer useful and comments *are supposed to be transient*.