# What does the number in front of each comment mean?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-votes

I wonder what it means. Is it voting?

If yes, how?

If not, then?

Comment: Yes it is. Your reputation is too low to [leave a comment on any question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and so you cannot yet do so yourself. Just wait a bit for those last few points.

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*?! See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: @Jongware no, you need 15 rep for upvoting posts and comments

Comment: @jonrsharpe got that!

Comment: see also: [Can comment votes sometimes be misleading?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299300/839601)

Comment: see also: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/288751)

Answer (score 2):

It is the number of upvotes that a comment has received.

Once you have enough reputation, you can [vote comments up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/165773). (Unlike questions and answers, however, they cannot be voted down).

In this way we can express our agreement with a comment, saving the comment section from things like "me too" or "I second what @... is saying".