# Declined NaA flag although the answerer agreed to flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe/31542594#31542594) but the flag was declined.

But as you can see the author of the answer agreed that this is not an answer.

Comment: Eh? Why isn't that one an answer?

Comment: Even though the answerer agreed with you, I personally think it is actually an answer.  The answer is "This issue may be resolved in the latest version of CocoaPods (reference)."

Comment: [Don't I know you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe/31542594#comment52310046_31542594) Sorry, made me laugh. But yeah it would be better as a comment if the OP had enough rep but it still *is an answer*. Just not a great one. A guess at an answer can be an answer. Though, aren't always well received

Comment: @ryanyuyu I see your point. Still "may be" sounds like speculating - not like answering. So it would better as a comment. And the only reason the author didn't make it a comment was low rep.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi it seems the answerer backed-into a real answer.  This is kinda a case of the poor intention producing a good outcome.  The fact remains that it does actually answer the question.  It is more appropriate as a comment?  Possibly.  Is it NAA?  No.  If you feel the answer is unhelpful or inaccurate, feel free to downvote.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Accepted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974/are-link-only-answers-pointing-to-resolved-bug-reports-answers/303980#303980

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your flag was correctly declined.  The answer does answer the question.  Paraphrasing a little bit the Q&A can be reduced to:

Question:

> How I can fix [the installation dependencies]?

Answer:

> This issue [has been fixed and doesn't exist anymore] in the latest version of CocoaPods (reference).

That's definitely an answer and a potentially useful one at that.  It's really nice to know that a problem can be fixed by updating.  So that's why your flag was declined.  More on [properly flagging as NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer).

---

Regarding the comments on the answer.

> This is not an answer. It is a guess together with a link. It is more a comment than an answer.

That's not quite accurate.  Guesses that answer the question are still answers.  I personally believe that it is more appropriate as an answer that a comment.  [Comment voting is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299300/can-comment-votes-sometimes-be-misleading) because you can't downvote comments.

> I thought same and I tried, but I could not add a comment due to my reputation is low...

It seems that the answerer got a bit lucky this time and backed-into a real answer. This is kinda a case of the poor intention producing a good outcome. The fact remains that it does actually answer the question.  Now, it would probably be a good idea to inform the user why leaving comments as answers is wrong to prevent future problems.  Their next comment-like answer might really be NAA.  Instructing them would be appropriate.

Comment: I tend to dislike (and flag) scattershot guesses posted as answers, but it's true that if the guess turned out correct, there's not much point in trying to delete it. Just edit the sucker to pretend they knew it all along.

Comment: Surely, I think my answer may helps someone. It should not be declined. Thank you. (and sorry for too late message.)

Answer (score 5):

The author of a post tends to be an unreliable narrator. Being new, especially, I wouldn't be surprised if this user was so overwhelmed by the policies and nuances we impose upon answers that they simple cannot accurately judge whether their answer qualifies as NAA, or something else, if at all.

Yes, the user meant to post a comment, but since they couldn't, they posted an answer instead. But it turns out that what they posted is technically an answer, since it offers a resolution for the problem rather than ignoring it entirely and going on a tirade of some sort.

But let's leave the hair-splitting to the reviewers and the mods. Personally, I don't see anything about this answer that necessitates a deletion. I'd just ignore it. I wouldn't even vote on it, because there is just nothing about this answer that stands out, whether positively or negatively. If *anything* at all, I'd probably flag the editorial comments as obsolete, and *then* move on.