# Comment links use the wrong GET arg for the visible tab

Tags: bug, status-deferred, comments, pagination, permalink

See comments on this answer:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387986/500202

GeorgeStocker attempted to post this link to one of his other comments:  `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments?page=2&tab=oldest#comment717700_387981` ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments?page=2&tab=oldest#comment717700_387981))

If you were viewing by votes, the page doesn't scroll to the comment, because with that order it's on page 1, not 2, and this URL isn't switching the tab.

The tabs use `&answertab=` instead of `&tab=` to switch, so changing that part of the URL makes this work regardless of your chosen one (but also changes your preferred order, so just changing the URLs is probably not the right fix).

Comment: Good find on this.

Answer (score 4):

The bug here is that the URL path doesn't include the answer ID. If it did, the system could find it no matter *which* page it ended up on - and to be clear, there's *never* a guarantee that an answer will be on a fixed page number.

Example: [Should the mod team tighten up moderation on Meta comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments/387981?page=2&tab=oldest#comment717700_387981) is the same URL, with the same parameters, but with the addition of the answer ID to the path - it works, and should continue to work no matter how many additional answers are posted, how the scores change, etc.

Getting rid of the tab param is also a good idea; nobody likes to have their preferences changed by clicking on a link.

### See also: [Links to comments on answers break when the answer moves to a different page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290082/links-to-comments-on-answers-break-when-the-answer-moves-to-a-different-page)