# Has the comment handling on Meta changed?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

This is related to [Should the mod team tighten up moderation on Meta comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments)

I see that the question is not featured any more, so my assumption is that the moderation team does not need any more input from users, thus a decision has been reached. However, I don't know what the decision is.

Comment: we still haven't reached a consensus as a team.

Comment: @YvetteColomb was un-featuring the discussion a team decision?

Comment: @l4mpi No, not at all. The reason we're being quiet is because we are not actually sure what to say. It's not sinister. Everyone is tired as well, so no one wants undue stress.

Comment: @l4mpi it doesn’t work like that. Moderators don’t “ask permission” before doing something (nor do we operate as a democracy), it’s more akin to “I did x, here’s why. Undo it if you are really dead set against why I did it.” I agree with it being unfeatured, and left my reasoning in a response to a flag; even though I’m not the one that unfeatured it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ok, thanks. I know that's how it usually works, but because the mod proposal and discussion seems to be a team effort, I thought that any changes or results to the proposal would also be made by the team as a whole as opposed to individual mods. As an aside, un-featuring the post after such a short time seems like somebody actively does not want more eyeballs on that question.

Comment: Incidentally, there wasn't consensus among the moderators whether or not we should have even posted that post, let alone feature it.