# What were the absolute numbers of comments 18 months ago compared to now?

Tags: support, statistics

In a recent [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/?cb=1) Sara Chipps wrote:

> ... we’ve seen a
>   reduction in the odds of a new comment being detected as abusive go
>   from 2.6% of new comments down to 1.3% in the past 18 months.

I am wondering what the total numbers of comments were 18 months ago and what they are now and how the numbers changed each month.

I am wondering if the interaction rate has increased, decreased or has stayed pretty much the same.

Comment: This seems like a use case for the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). The only trouble is that it's updated once a week, so many obsolete comments may have been flagged and deleted by the weekly captures.

Comment: Also many people simply stopped commenting completely.

Comment: We know that moderators are being [more vigilant in removing comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments). I wonder if this means there's less comments left around to be flagged as abusive as they're being more proactively handled.

Comment: You mean the lower detection rate could simply be a side-effect of an overall lower activity? Maybe we can correlate weekdays vs. weekend-days (weekend-days have typically lower overall activity). Unfortunately, we don't have their detector rates for weekdays and weekend days available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can view the number of comments per month using [this query by rene](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1125718#graph).

[image]

As can be seen, the amount of comments on Stack Overflow have seen a steady decrease since 2017. From 2018 to now, it's gone from approximately 725K per month to just above 600K per month. Since we don't have the exacts on the measurement interval, we can't make exact conclusions.

However, we can be certain that while the amount of comments decreased, the amount of comments hasn't halved in that period.

Comment: It all seems to go down. Answers are at the frequency of 2011. Quality of answers... who knows.

Comment: This doesn't amount for deleted comments, does it?

Comment: @E_Bob4 Nope, we don't have access to that, only the CMs do.

Comment: My point is that this makes a significant difference. The query does not measure comments already detected as abusive.